# android connected with ftp

Tags: android, ftp

I have download the below code from [this website](http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/android-start-ftp-android/)

I can successfully login in filezilla client. But when i typed the same information in this app, it shows (unable to perform action). can anyone help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final String TEMP_FILENAME = "TAGtest.txt";
private Context cntx = null;

private MyFTPClientFunctions ftpclient = null;

private Button btnLoginFtp, btnUploadFile, btnDisconnect, btnExit;
private EditText edtHostName, edtUserName, edtPassword;
private ProgressDialog pd;

private String[] fileList;

private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        if (pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            getFTPFileList();
        } else if (msg.what == 1) {
            showCustomDialog(fileList);
        } else if (msg.what == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded Successfully!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (msg.what == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Disconnected Successfully!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to Perform Action!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cntx = this.getBaseContext();

    edtHostName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHostName);
    edtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUserName);
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

    btnLoginFtp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginFtp);
    btnUploadFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadFile);
    btnDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisconnectFtp);
    btnExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

    btnLoginFtp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnUploadFile.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDisconnect.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Create a temporary file. You can use this to upload
    createDummyFile();

    ftpclient = new MyFTPClientFunctions();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnLoginFtp:
        if (isOnline(MainActivity.this)) {
            connectToFTPAddress();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Please check your internet connection!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btnUploadFile:
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading...",
                true, false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                boolean status = false;
                status = ftpclient.ftpUpload(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/TAGFtp/" + TEMP_FILENAME,
                        TEMP_FILENAME, "/", cntx);
                if (status == true) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Upload success");
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Upload failed");
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        break;
    case R.id.btnDisconnectFtp:
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Disconnecting...",
                true, false);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ftpclient.ftpDisconnect();
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
            }
        }).start();

        break;
    case R.id.btnExit:
        this.finish();
        break;
    }

}

private void connectToFTPAddress() {

    final String host = edtHostName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String username = edtUserName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = edtPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (host.length() < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Host Address!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (username.length() < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter User Name!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (password.length() < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Password!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Connecting...",
                true, false);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                boolean status = false;
                status = ftpclient.ftpConnect(host, username, password, 21);
                if (status == true) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Success");
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed");
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

private void getFTPFileList() {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Getting Files...",
            true, false);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            fileList = ftpclient.ftpPrintFilesList("/");
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }
    }).start();
}

public void createDummyFile() {

    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "TAGFtp");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, TEMP_FILENAME);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append("Hi this is a sample file to upload for android FTP client example from TheAppGuruz!");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved : " + gpxfile.getAbsolutePath(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void showCustomDialog(String[] fileList) {
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.setTitle("/ Directory File List");

    TextView tvHeading = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvListHeading);
    tvHeading.setText(":: File List ::");

    if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.lstItemList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> fileListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
        listView.setAdapter(fileListAdapter);
    } else {
        tvHeading.setText(":: No Files ::");
    }

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

}

Comment: You could at least tell us what you where type in. And what you expect to happen.

Comment: `i can sucessfully login in filezilla server.` ??? Do you mean: "With the FileZilla client on my PC I can log in at that FTP server"?

Comment: Is it your own FTP server where you try to login?

Comment: `"Unable to Perform Action!",`. Which action? You have twice `handler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);` in your code. Add more values to distinguish.

Comment: yes,my own ftp server. and i created a user,, username: test1 , password: test1 ,, server name is my own ip :138.xxx.xxx.xxx  .     i can sucessfully login in filezilla client on my own pc

Comment: maybe you can simply download the demo from the website,, i hard to describe the situation

Comment: when i tried to connect to ftp with the same information,, it said unable to perform action

Comment: Moved the text from the boittom to the top to better help frame the question. Moved the URL into a link to clean up the text. Fixed typos and changed above to below

Comment: `I can successfully login in filezilla server`. Are you leaving that on the second line?

Comment: changed,do you have some idea about that??

Comment: `I can successfully login in filezilla client.`. It would be nice if you could better explain what you ment by this. Do i have to help you with that?  Or will rereading my comments do?